# Firebase Realtime Database add to list in MutableData

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I add to a list in a Firebase Realtime Database transaction using MutableData?

In a normal non-transaction type update, I can simply use

```
DatabaseReference refDatabase = ...    
refDatabase.push().setValue(value);
```

But with MutableData, no such push() method exists.  How to add to a list and get a unique key?

I'm looking for something like

```
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
      mutableData.push().setValue(value);
       ...
```

but this does not exist.

Comment: Calling `push()` is a pure client-side operation. You can call `refDatabase.push().getKey()` and get a unique key from anywhere in your code. If you're having trouble making your transaction work, show the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen, that solves the unique key problem, but it doesn't show how to add to a list with MutableData as I think I have clearly asked.  It's not so much providing minimal code to reproduce a problem as showing that a method that I need does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the point of your question and comment: It would be nice to know if the absence of `push()` was an oversight by the API designers, or it was intentionally omitted to prevent users from doing something that was unsafe or otherwise "bad".

There is a workaround, right?  You know the reference the transaction is run on.  The mutable data is the value of that reference location.  Can't you just make the reference variable a package field, or a `final` class variable, and use it in the callback to call `push()`?  It's ugly, but I think should work.

I'll also take a guess that `push()` was omitted from `MutableData` for a reason.  The [documentation for doTransaction()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler) states:

> This method will be called, possibly multiple times, with the current
>   data at this location. It is responsible for inspecting that data and
>   returning a Transaction.Result specifying either the desired new data
>   at the location or that the transaction should be aborted.
>
> Since this method may be called repeatedly for the same transaction,
>   be extremely careful of any side effects that may be triggered by this
>   method.

Maybe generating keys and adding elements to a list is not something you want to be doing, since it may occur multiple times.